# Salvar uma valor de um data frame sem que ele seja perdido quando seja atualizado

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tentando salvar o primeiro valor desse dataframe em uma variável que o valor não será perdido quando a tabela que gera o dado for atualizada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use o método `.copy` para copiar um DataFrame/Series do pandas. A partir desse momento, os dados original e copiado podem ser modificados de forma independente.

Exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [10, 20, 30],
})

print(df)
# output:
#    a   b
# 0  1  10
# 1  2  20
# 2  3  30

df_copia = df.copy()  # cópia independente
df['a'] = ['outros', 'valores', 'aqui']

print(df)  # valores modificados
# output:
#          a   b
# 0   outros  10
# 1  valores  20
# 2     aqui  30

print(df_copia)  # valores originais
# output:
#    a   b
# 0  1  10
# 1  2  20
# 2  3  30
```

No seu caso, imagino que você queira fazer algo do tipo:

```
Lastdate = T_Newbloqueio.iloc[0]['databloqueio'].copy()
```